# How to conditionally select rows based on other rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, subquery, relational-division

I've got two tables with a simple 1:n relation. One table contains ingredients and their availability. The other contains recipes and their respective ingredients.

Table recipes

```
RecipeA   | IngredientA
RecipeA   | IngredientB
RecipeB   | IngredientA
RecipeB   | IngredientC
```

and table ingredients

```
IngredientA | true
IngredientB | true
IngredientC | false
```

Querying all rows of table recipes where the ingredient is available is trivial. But how do I select only recipes where ALL ingredients are available? The result should be

```
RecipeA
```

I assume it can be done with the `ALL` operator but I didn't succeed yet. I tried without success

```
SELECT Recipe 
FROM tblRecipes  
WHERE Ingredient = ALL ( 
  SELECT Ingredient  
  FROM tblIngredients  
  WHERE Available
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select r.recipe
from recipes as r inner join
     ingredients as i
     on r.ingredient = i.ingredient
group by r.recipe
having sum(iif(i.available = "false", 1, 0)) = 0;
```

The `sum()` is counting the number of non-available ingredients for a given recipe.  The `= 0` means that none are "not available".

By the way, the data model is poorly named.  You should have three tables:

- `Recipes` with one row per recipe.
- `Ingredients` with one row per ingredient.
- `RecipeIngredients` with one row per ingredient in each recipe.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice approach. I assume you mean `on r.ingredient = i.ingredient`

Comment: Note: MS Access SQL requires `join` to be specific: `inner join`, `left join`, etc. Otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: @Parfait It also requires `i.available = false` with no quotation marks, or alternatively `i.available = 0`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually have 3 tables as you suggested, I thought it would complicate the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an aggregate query with `HAVING` condition to check recipe counts against available ingredients count. The conditional aggregation is multiplied by -1 due to Access value of `True` boolean at -1.

```sql
SELECT r.Recipe 
FROM tblRecipes r
INNER JOIN Ingredient i 
  r.recipe = i.recipe
GROUP BY r.Recipe
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(i.available = 'true') * -1
```